# Save files missing after restarting the game

Tags: zapper-one-wicked-cricket

I recently found a zapper installed on my computer. The game runs fine but at the end of each level i get a msg. (the msg is in russian) I am assuming the msg says that the game cannot save my progress. As soon as i turn off the game i loose all my progress and the game starts from beginning. this doesnt happen on my brothers computer.

print screen comes out all black :/
I run windows 8 on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the program as an administrator fixed the problem.